# Implement SMS API in Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, api, sms

I am developing a Java Application to send SMS to group or a single person through application. I have bought an API from [LifeTimeSMS](http://lifetimesms.com/). This is a URL Based API as I shared my code below.

```
String sendernum = sender.getText();
        String msg = message.getText();
        String num = singlenum.getText();
        String request = "http://Lifetimesms.com/plain?username=username&password=pass&to="+num+"&from="+sendernum+"&message="+msg+"";
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(request);
            HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            System.out.println(uc.getResponseMessage());
            if(uc.getResponseMessage().equals("OK"))
            {
            successSent a = new successSent();
            a.setVisible(true);
            }
            else
            {
                sendingFailed sf = new sendingFailed();
                sf.setVisible(true);
            }
            uc.disconnect();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
```

and this is the API documentation of the site from where I have purchased the API.

[API Documentation](http://lifetimesms.com/api-documentations.php)

**Problem that I am facing**

When I sent an SMS through URL (Direct putting URL on Google Chrome or any browser) the sms will successfully sent.

But when I send SMS through my application, it will skip the text after space [  ].

Just like if I sent "Hi How are you" then text will go "Hi".

If I sent "Hi.How.are.you" then this text will sent as I wrote.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You need to `URLEncode` the parameter values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> URLEncode

Above method worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your `msg` string write this type `msg='\"+msg+"\'`